# Typescript can't understand nullish-coalescing

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, build

I'm using an external package (`@moj/pagination-layout`) inside Vue + TypeScript app,  this package uses nullish operator inside of it but when I try to run `build` it fails and give me this error

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                1:10:16 PM

 error  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/components/table/helpers/mixin-sorting.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (245:53)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|       const sortable = field.sortable
>       const sortKey = !localSorting ? field.sortKey ?? key : key
|
|       // Assemble the aria-sort attribute value

 @ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/components/table/table.js 19:0-77 42:7-19 76:4-16
 @ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--13-1!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/@moj/pagination-layout/src/components/PaginationLayout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "watch": "vue-cli-service build --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@moj/pagination-layout": "^1.0.14",
    "@t2/data-table": "0.1.3",
    "@t2/wizard": "0.2.1",
    "file-saver": "2.0.2",
    "i": "0.3.6",
    "izitoast": "1.4.0",
    "register-service-worker": "1.6.2",
    "vue": "2.6.10",
    "vue-application-insights": "^1.0.7",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-class-component": "7.1.0",
    "vue-di-container": "0.1.0",
    "vue-i18n": "8.12.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "8.1.1",
    "vue-router": "3.1.0",
    "vue-template-loader": "1.0.0",
    "vuetify": "1.5.14",
    "vuex": "3.1.1",
    "vuex-class": "0.3.2",
    "coa": "2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.4.4",
    "@types/file-saver": "2.0.1",
    "@types/node": "12.7.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.15.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.15.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.16",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^10.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vuejs-accessibility": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "1.5.1",
    "stylus": "0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "3.0.2",
    "typescript": "3.5.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-axios": "0.0.4",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "0.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.1"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "ClientApp/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "ClientApp/**/*.ts",
    "ClientApp/**/*.tsx",
    "ClientApp/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**babel.config.json**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@vue/app',
      {
        useBuiltIns: 'entry',
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      'transform-imports',
      {
        vuetify: {
          transform: 'vuetify/es5/components/${member}',
          preventFullImport: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Any clue?

Comment: TypeScript can handle ?? just fine, but isn't expecting to transpile code in node_modules.

Comment: It's not TS but Babel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60823931/how-to-add-babel-support-for-nullishcoalescingoperator-to-vue-project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Babel support for nullishCoalescingOperator to vue project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60823931/how-to-add-babel-support-for-nullishcoalescingoperator-to-vue-project)

Answer (score 0):

This error is generally due to the fact that your module is not transpiled by babel.

In your [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) file, you can set an option called: [`transpileDependencies`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#transpiledependencies). Just put the name of the module whose dependencies you want to transpile into an array of strings, and everything should work like magic.

Example:

```js
module.exports = {
    transpileDependencies: ['bootstrap-vue']
}
```